# Install canon printer Pixma TS5350a

Tags: 22.04

I operate Ubuntu in 64 bit 22.04.2 LTS and cannot print from new Canon PIXMA TS5350a. Which driver do I download and in which directory do I install the driver? what instructions do I give the terminal?

Comment: 64bit isn't very helpful; as you've not said if you're talking about 64bit ARM (*arm64*), 64bit PPC (*ppc64el*), 64bit AMD (*amd64*), etc. As all architectures are now 64-bit except ARM (*armhf* for 32-bit) did you mention 64-bit because it's a ARM based machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this file from the Canon website:
https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts5350a.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1881244&os=linux%20%2864-bit%29&language=en

When you download it, extract it, you can also use the file explorer of ubuntu.
Next step open up the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and navigate inside the extracted folder, where you can see the file called "install.sh", then type

> ./install.sh

Comment: Thanks for replying,Simone. I am new to all this and have got this far.